# AngularJS - How to pass different $scope attributes to a directive through attrs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to load excerpts of copy that are selected by the `ver="..."` attribute which is populated by the scope.

```
app.directive('hymn', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{ },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.contentUrl = 'content/excerpts/hymn-' + attrs.ver + '.html';        
                attrs.$observe("ver", function (v) {
                    scope.contentUrl = 'content/excerpts/hymn-' + v + '.html';    
                });
            },
        template: '<div><p ng-include="contentUrl"></p></div>'
    }
})
```

There are  multiple instances of the `<hymn ver="hymn-{{scope.date.weekday}}-{{scope.date.season}}"></hymn>`, `<hymn ver="hymn-{{scope.date.week}}"></hymn>` in a single template and each will pull a different excerpt.

If I comment out `scope:{},` I get the first instance successfully but repeated at every `<hymn>` node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a *child* `$scope` for each directive by using `scope: true` instead of isolating the `$scope` using `scope: {}`.

Inheriting the properties from the parent will allow you to `$eval` the strings in `attr.ver` inside the directive.

Answer (score 1):

`scope:{ }` makes an isolate scope so the directive has no access to anything else in it

What it looks like you want is:

```
scope: {
  ver: '@'
}
```

Then change references in link function to `scope.ver`. Have a read up about isolate scopes on google.

Comment: I suspect that this will not interpolate the values `{{scope.date.weekday}}` into the string for `ver`. One will still need access to the parent scope to be able to `$eval` the string.

Comment: @ed-hinchliffe,  
I definitely need further reading. I started this project as a dive off the deep-end into angular. Needless to say it has some deep waters. Thank you for the direction.